# Put contents of Set<Object> into Array

Tags: java

I'm sure this is an easy one.  I just want to dump the set after the for loop in to the array of type `Role`

This is what I got:

```
Role[] hotRoles; 
Set <Role> roles = profile.getRoles(Section);

    for (Role role : roles  )
    {
        if( role.getName().contains("PART") && !role.getName().contains("READ_ONLY") ) 
        {
        System.out.println("Role: " + role.getName());
        }
    }
```

I want to put the vaues that come back from the for loop into `hotPartRoles`

thanks.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you only want the elements that are *printed* to go into the array?

You have to do this dynamically, since you don't know in advance how many elements there will be.

Something like

```
List<Role> hotRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();
for(Role role : roles) {
  if(...) {
    hotRoles.add(role);
    ...
  }
}
hotPartRoles = hotRoles.toArray(new Role[hotRoles.size()]);
```

Comment: `hotRoles.size()` is not necessary, `hotRoles.toArray(new Role[0])` will work as well, the array will be sized automatically

Comment: It's a matter of preference -- I prefer this approach because it doesn't allocate and then immediately discard a `Role[]` of length `0`, and doesn't require reflectively allocating a new array.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks, I never checked how `toArray()` is actually implemented, good to know

Answer (score 2):

```
Role[] hotPartRoles = roles.toArray(new Role[roles.length]);
```